# How to make sure that std::random_shuffle always produces a different result?

Tags: c++, random, std, shuffle

Is there some function, similar to `srand()`, that I need to call to make sure that `std::random_shuffle()` always produces different results? i.e. if I call it several times with the same data, I want the order to be different every time. How can I make sure of that?

Comment: That doesn't sound very random to me...

Comment: @Blindy: It's random, but the results are not uniformly distributed.

Comment: srand is quite good. If it is not good enough for your need, search for other random generators (maybe boost)

Comment: Make sure you **NEVER** call srand() more than once in a program.

Comment: `srand()` doesn't make sure anything produces different results. @John: it's less and less random each time, because it's more and more predictable each time.

Comment: @LokiAstari there are plenty of reasons to.  If you care about running a MC algorithm multiple times with different parameters but the same random number stream, for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::random_shuffle` has two forms.  One that takes 2 arguments (begin/end iterators), and one that takes 3 (begin/end iterator and a random generator).

The first form uses `std::rand()`, so you would use `std::srand()` to seed it's random number generator.  You can also use the 3-argument version and provide the RNG yourself.

Comment: As I understand it, how the first form implements it is its business.  Some platforms may not use `std::rand`.

Comment: You're right.  I was looking at the libstdc++ version.  The original author should consult the documentation for your STL.  Or if they don't want to rely on that, they should use the 3rd form and use something like `boost::random` or the C++0x `std::random`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::random_shuffle` has a template overload for specifying the RNG.

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class RandomNumberGenerator>
  void random_shuffle ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                        RandomNumberGenerator& rand );
```

[reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)

Answer (score 5):

random_shuffle is deprecated since C++14 (removed in C++17) and replaced with shuffle (exists since C++11)
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

possible usage:

```
shuffle(items.begin(), items.end(), std::default_random_engine(std::random_device()()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can give a random generator functor to std::random_shuffle, so you can be able to fully control the random number generation. Looking [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/random_shuffle.html), this functor takes the place of the RandomNumberGenerator template argument.

Answer (score 3):

Generally call `srand(time(NULL))` **before** calling `std::random_shuffle()` would give you what you need, it give you different result each time you call `std::random_shuffle()`. It's because `std::random_shuffle()` internally calls `rand()` in many popular implementations (e.g. VS-2008 and GCC).

Of course you can supple a RNG yourself if you want to call the other overloaded `std::random_shuffle` with a extra parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As a last resort, you can:

- Call `std::random_shuffle`
- Compute a hash of the sequence, store it in a `std::set`
- Discard if the hash is already present

I fail to see how using a custom generator could *guarantee* that the sequence is unique.